# Set Windows2012R2 resolution remotely

Tags: powershell, vmware-vsphere

I am trying to set the graphic resolution remotely.
I cannot use the Set-DisplayResolution, since it does not work with Windows2012R2.
I can use the system32 utility setres.exe to do it locally, but when I try to invoke it from a PS targeting the remote machine I get an error saying that the operation cannot be performed.

This is my PS code:

```
$s = New-PSSession -computername $CurrentMachineName -credential $cred
Invoke-Command -session $s -scriptblock {c:\windows\system32\setres.exe -w 1280 -h 1024}
Remove-PSSession $s
```

The remote machine(s) are VMWare clones of the same template, but the resolution does not appear to get carried over while cloning.

Any idea?

Comment: Difficult to help without seeing your actual code, maybe you are using a local variable for the resolution and don't use `$using:variable` ?

Comment: Added the code to the question

Comment: Why the resolution need ? as with rdp remotly it will adjust to your local resolution. Only thing that can block is if no graphic card is setupped correctly

Comment: @MaPi are you sure that 1280x1024 is a valid resolution option for the VM?